# how to solve folowing equation using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

3553200 = 27 × (√n/5)

3553200 = 1560878×log2(n)/13

3553200 = 9^n−2

I have tried the following code:

```
from math import sqrt
from sympy import symbols, solve,Eq
import math
exp=27*(sqrt(n)/5)-3553200
print(solve(exp))
```

But it gives error:

```
TypeError: can't convert expression to float

exp=(1560878*log(n))/13-3553200
print(solve(exp))
NameError: name 'log' is not defined
```

Comment: This code cannot produce this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your `log` throws an error because you either have to type it as `math.log()` or `import log from math`.

As for the `sqrt` function: when I run it on my machine with the exact same imports, it throws a `NameError: name 'sqrt' is not defined`, so perhaps you should provide the full code for us to see what's happening. There's probably a missing line.

In any case, you should be able to run the code by using `math.sqrt()` or

```py
import sympy 
sympy.sqrt()
```

instead of `sqrt()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `n` as a `sympy.Symbol` and use `sqrt` and other functions imported from `sympy`. See [sympy documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html).

```py
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol, sqrt
n = Symbol('n')
exp=27*(sqrt(n)/5)-3553200
print(solve(exp, n))
```

prints:

```
[432964000000]
```

[Verification](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=27*%28sqrt%28n%29%2F5%29-3553200+%3D+0&dataset=)

Comment: thanks ..that was usefull...I think the proplem was I used sqrt() from math not sympy

Answer (score -2):

also import log
from math import sqrt   ,log

add quotes
exp="27*(sqrt(n)/5)-3553200"
exp="(1560878*log(n))/13-3553200"

Comment: - my answer came first, would print correct solutions, least changes  
- docs.sympy.org: ["The other solution is to put quotes around the expression .."](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html)